# Changing UITextView height on orientation change with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a big `UITextView` in it. I created a constraint to make the text view width 100%, I now would like the textview to resize in height when orientation changes and I can't find how to do this.

Here's my code for now:

```
var wordLabel = UITextView()
wordLabel.attributedText = wordText
wordLabel.editable = false
wordLabel.scrollEnabled = false
wordLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let wordLabelSize = wordLabel.sizeThatFits(maxLabelsSize)
wordLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, wordLabelSize.width, wordLabelSize.height)
wordLabel.center = CGPoint(x: wordLabel.frame.width / 2, y: wordLabel.frame.height / 2)
scrollView.addSubview(wordLabel)


let wordLabelConstraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: -32)
scrollView.addConstraint(wordLabelConstraintWidth)

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width - 32, height: wordLabel.frame.origin.y + wordLabel.frame.height)
```

`scrollView` and `wordLabel` sizes are correct when the app launches but when orientation changes to landscape, the scroll gets too high.

I don't really know how to recalculate `scrollView` contentSize on orientation change, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have two way:

1. Set a constraint for the height, and do something like:

   ```
   wordLabelConstraintHeight.costant = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) ? 60.0 : 25.0;
   ```
2. If the `textView` should resize itself proportionally with the screen, you can use the **multiplier**:

   ```
   let wordLabelConstraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0)
   ```

   For example this code make the height of your `textView`, the 20% of the frame of your `scrollView` that I'm sure is changing according with the screen size and so according with the orientation of the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The textview is of the same height as the scrollview so I just had to do this:
`let wordLabelConstraintsHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[wordLabel]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["wordLabel": wordLabel])`

Just figured it out!

Comment: Oh LOL..but I thought was not this the case as yes, obviously you can use visual format if you need just to attach the border of the textView to the border of his superview with a costant value. ;)